# How do I exclude the filename from __init__.py when using import

Tags: python, import, package

### Problem

In the `__init__.py` that I have inside the folder phpjunkie.

```py
from .win32 import GetWindowHandle, CaptureWwindow, FocusWindow, AlwaysOnTop, ShowHideWindow
from .timelapse import Timelapse
from .fps import FPS
```

When I use `import phpjunkie` in a script it shows the filenames (win32, timelapse, fps) in [PyCharm's drop down box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B706s.png). This is a compiled package and I don't want the filenames themselves to be accessible. How do I exclude them?

---

### Conclusion

I found away around this problem with the `setup.py`. I was able to get rid of the files showing in the drop down box by leaving out the `packages = ['phpjunkie']` and using `package_dir = {'': 'phpjunkie'}` and `py_modules = ['phpjunkie', 'Win32']`.

```py
import setuptools

setuptools.setup(
    name = 'phpjunkie',
    version = '0.0.27',
    package_dir = {
        '': 'phpjunkie'
    },
    py_modules = ['phpjunkie', 'Win32'],
    author = 'phpjunkie',
    install_requires = ['pywin32', 'numpy'],
)
```

The `packages = ['phpjunkie']` was the source of the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming this is your package structure:

```
phpjunkie
|_ __init__.py
|_ win32.py
|_ timelapse.py
|_ fps.py
```

The reason you see `win32`, `timelapse` and `fps` in the namespace of `phpjunkie` is not because they are "called" in the `__init__.py`, but because they are individual modules within `phpjunkie`.

To remove them, you need to overwrite the `__all__`  attribute which is the list of public object of that module. By default, anything starting with an underscore is considered private and is not listed. Thus 2 options:

- Rename the files to start with an underscore (making them private)
- Overwrite `__all__` in the `__init__.py`, e.g.

```
from .win32 import GetWindowHandle, CaptureWwindow, FocusWindow, AlwaysOnTop, ShowHideWindow
from .timelapse import Timelapse
from .fps import FPS

__all__ = ["GetWindowHandle", "CaptureWwindow", ...]  # I let you complete
```

Answer (score 0):

I found away around this problem with the `setup.py`.

This is what I had.

```py
import setuptools

setuptools.setup(
    name = 'phpjunkie',
    version = '0.0.27',
    packages = ['phpjunkie'],
    author = 'phpjunkie',
    install_requires = ['pywin32', 'numpy'],
```

I was able to get rid of the files showing in the drop down box by leaving out the `packages = ['phpjunkie']` and using `package_dir = {'': 'phpjunkie'}` and `py_modules = ['phpjunkie', 'Win32']`.

```py
import setuptools

setuptools.setup(
    name = 'phpjunkie',
    version = '0.0.27',
    package_dir = {
        '': 'phpjunkie'
    },
    py_modules = ['phpjunkie', 'Win32'],
    author = 'phpjunkie',
    install_requires = ['pywin32', 'numpy'],
)
```

The `packages = ['phpjunkie']` was the source of the problem.